# How to customize nautilus files view in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: nautilus, customization, 17.04

I want all Nautilus windows/folders to show file listings the same customized way.

On Windows I'd simply configure a single folder like I want, open options, click "set all folders like this one" (or something on those lines, don't remember the exact button label)

On Nautilus (Ubuntu file manager) I can configure a single folder at a time. And this site has dozen of answered questions on how to reset all folders to default, but I can't find anything on how to set all folders to my custom style.

Which is as shown bellow.

[image: nautilus]

This would be my simple preferred view, with size before name.

Edit for clarity: I do Not want to set this on thousands of folders. I want my way to be the default everywhere.

Comment: If I understood it correct, then you want your file manager to look like what is shown in the image. Am I right?

Comment: yes. I can easily do that for a single folder. But i want that for everything always.

Comment: If you are able to do it for a single folder, then the same settings get applied automatically to all the folders (well atleast in my system).

Can you tell me how did you do it for a single folder?

Comment: if relevant I am on latest ubuntu 17.04. They renamed Nautilus to Files (really...) version 3.20.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no solution using ubuntu's default file manager.

per folder settings is now mandatory per design apparently. I couldn't find any commit explicitly mentioning that change, but didn't look too hard.

Easy solution is to install the Cinamon desktop file manager: Nemo.

```
apt-get install nemo-fileroller
```

(install this so it draws all few dependencies, including nemo, and you already can have 'extract here' features)

After installing nemo and replacing your shortcuts in the launcher, there is a setting to "ignore per folder view preferences"

Answer (score 2):

Open nautilus, from menu select: "Edit" -> "Preferences", "Views" tab.

Set default view as "List view":

[image]

Then go to "list columns" tab and config it like this:

[image]

Comment: Don't you have to go to "List Columns" tab to select which details you want to see in list view?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add that too ;) Didn't pay attention to that ... thanks.

Comment: Not that easy. This was the very first thing i did. it will only set the custom column order for the ONE SINGLE folder i'm viewing. e.g. do that in $home. Now just double click any folder in the very window you just set up. Bam! listing view with default ordered columns. :(

Comment: Works fine for me, not only my home and all sub directories of home are using same schema, also `/` and all its sub directories now are using it.

Comment: are you using ubuntu 17.04? @Ravexina

Comment: @gcb No, I'm running 16.04 :-)

Comment: yeah i think there is noworkaround for 17.04 then :/

Comment: I'm not aware of it, you can update you question with more information if any, then more people may see it ...

Comment: @Ravexina its on the title :)

Comment: I meant aware of if it's possible or not... ;)