# change default gnome filemanager

Tags: gnome, 17.10, preferences

The current gnome file manager lacks some very basic functionality, for example setting a [default folder view](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914898/how-to-customize-nautilus-files-view-in-ubuntu-17-04). My solution was to start using Nemo file manager instead.

It solved my problem except where applications insists on something else. For example, on Firefox downloads, if I select "open containing folder" it will open on the feature-less File application instead of Nemo.

Where can I set a default file manager of my choosing, system wide? I am okay even with overriding the Files binary with a link to Nemo if it comes to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The xdg-mime program can be used to query information about file types and to add descriptions for new file types.
`default` -Ask the desktop environment to make application the default application for opening files of type mimetype. An application can be made the default for several file types by specifying multiple mimetypes.
Running the command below will set your default file manager to nemo.
For more information about xdg-mime read man file or check those links:
[Example how to change file manager](http://www.fandigital.com/2013/01/set-nemo-default-file-manager-ubuntu.html) or [man page](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-mime.html).

`xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search`

Comment: this seems like a xfce thing. i am unity (and can move to gnome). regardless i tried it, after installimg exo-utils i get; $ exo-preferred-applications
/usr/bin/exo-preferred-applications: 11: exec: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/exo-1/exo-helper-1: not found

Comment: Yeah, sorry my bad. I edited my answer now it should work.

Comment: @dessert i did quote the important part

Comment: @dessert i edited it so it has more information. Is it better now?

Comment: How come I can still open Nautilus using Firefox?